# Mongoose - asynchronous validation of schema object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to determine how to do asynchronous validation for a Mongoose schema - specifically in this case the username. TMK, to ensure that the username is unique, we have to manually query the database to see if the same username already exists. This is an asynchronous query. However the methodology of having a 'validate:' property for each schema item, seems to ask for a synchronous validation function. In other words, this line:

validate: [validation.usernameValidator, 'not a valid username']

seems to require that usernameValidator be synchronous, and the problem is I need it to be async, for the reason aforementioned.

So, I have a Mongoose schema for a User like so:

```
   var validation = {

        usernameValidator: function (candidate) {
            return true;
        },
        passwordValidator: function (candidate) {
            return true;
        }
    };


    userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        username: {
            type: String,
            isUnique: true,
            required: true,
            validate: [validation.usernameValidator, 'not a valid username']
        },
        passwordHash: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            validate: [validation.passwordValidator, 'not a valid password']
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            isUnique: true,
            required: true,
            validate: [validation.emailValidator, 'not a valid email address']
        }
    });

    userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

        var self = this;
        if (!self.isModified('passwordHash')) {
            return next();
        }

        bcrypt.hash(self.passwordPreHash, SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            else if(hash == null){
                return next(new Error('null/undefined hash'));
            }
            else {
                self.passwordHash = hash;
                next();
            }
        });
    });


//is the following function my best bet?
      userSchema.path('username').validate(function (value, respond){                                                                                           
    this.findOne({ username: value }, function (err, user){                                                                                                
            if(user)                                                                          respond(false);                                                                                                                         
       });                                                                                                                                                  
}, 'This username has been already registered');
```

is my only option to leave out the validation.usernameValidator methodology, and validate username with userSchema.path('username').validate..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose should handle this provided that you specify `unique: true` on that field.

For example

```
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
});
```

**ADDITION:**

Mongoose will declare a *unique index* provided that you specify such in your schema(as done in example above). This prevents having to query into mongodb to see if another document has a field of the same value. You can read about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique).

You can read more about Unique Indexes for mongodb [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/), if you'd like to learn more about their behaviour.

Note: A validation error will not be throw if a non-unique value is provided. See the mongoose docs for more info on this.

Comment: oh, that's why, I was using isUnique for it, and that wasn't doing anything, thanks.

Comment: Yep, you had it wrong. I wasn't sure if you were setting that for another reason. See my additions for more information that may be helpful when you implement this.